# What exactly am i looking for? HTML5 / Navigation Menu / Responsive

Tags: html

Hey so I came across this website
http://felixplus.com/demo/grid/html/skins/light/index.html

and it is responsive and all that - looks great.

Something I really want to do is learn how to mimic the Navigation Menu when you re-size the window.
A little box appears which is clickable and then there is a dropdown menu from there.

I was hoping someone could tell me what i needed to do or point me to somewhere so i can learn the technique.

I would google it myself and whatnot but I don't know what it is. Like is it jquery, bootstrap, something else? idk, please help and if i need to clarify what i am looking for again please post so you can be of assistance, thank you.

Comment: Its pure CSS, with @media queries

Comment: This kind of menus are created with css _media queries_ and css `transition`. If you only want to support modern browsers there is no need to use js for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just pure CSS with @media queries...

Heres a tutorial to get you started..

http://toddmotto.com/building-an-html5-responsive-menu-with-media-queries-javascript/

But Twitter Bootstrap has this functionality built right in, if you don't feel like learning the real nuts and bolts of it....

Just download bootstrap, and include this in your HTML...

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And youre responsive, OUT OF THE BOX!

More info here..

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Comment: thanks man, i wasn't sure if that was it but i also like learning the "real nuts and bolts of it" so i'll definitely check out the top link. if i cant i guess ill try the bootstrap plugin/thingy.